# Encoding French Characters, csv - PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am working on a project that exports a simple CSV. So far, my code works and generates the CSV as long as I use English characters.

Some column names will be in French and would like to be able to encode that.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php 
    // open the file "demosaved.csv" for writing
    $file = fopen('myfrench-export.csv', 'w');
    // save the column headers
    fputcsv($file, array('Question', 'Réponse 1/4', 'Réponse 2/4', 'Réponse 3/4', 'Réponse 4/4', 'Total completé', 'Total non-completé', 'Total cumulatif'));

    // Sample data. This can be fetched from mysql too
    $data = array(
        array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
        array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
        array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
        array('Data 41', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
        array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
        array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
        array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
        array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
    );

    // save each row of the data
    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($file, $row);
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose($file); ?>
```

Comment: What is causing the French text to be encoded as **"RÃ©ponse 3/4"** instead of  **"Réponse 3/4"** , and how  to fix it?

Comment: What OS do you code on? And what OS does your code run on?

Comment: I code on Windows 10, code runs locally on Xampp and remotely on Azure on a Wordpress App. Does it matter though?

Comment: using `mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'HTML-ENTITIES','utf-8' );` worked for me; whereas `utf8_decode` wasn't doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some checking around, I came across this answer and I adjusted this line by applying utf8_decode and that worked.

Basically I replaced

`fputcsv($file, array('Question', 'Réponse 1/4', 'Réponse 2/4', 'Réponse 3/4', 'Réponse 4/4', 'Total completé', 'Total non-completé', 'Total cumulatif'));`

With

```
$array = array_map("utf8_decode", array('Question', 'Réponse 1/4', 'Réponse 2/4', 'Réponse 3/4', 'Réponse 4/4', 'Total completé', 'Total non-completé', 'Total cumulatif'));
```

And that worked!

Comment: Not useful, what about the large data set ??

Comment: Map accordingly

Comment: I was  thinking that this code is useful but finally it was not.
Unfortunately I cannot undo my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use bom to allow to display special characters with excel.

This code can help you:

```php
// Open the file "demosaved.csv" for writing
$file = fopen('myfrench-export.csv', 'w');

// Mandatory: Use bom to allow to display special characters with excel
fwrite($file, $bom = chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF')));

// Save the column headers
fputcsv($file, array('Question', 'Réponse 1/4', 'Réponse 2/4', 'Réponse 3/4', 'Réponse 4/4', 'Total completé', 'Total non-completé', 'Total cumulatif'));

// Sample data. This can be fetched from mysql too
$data = array(
    array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
    array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
    array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
    array('Data 41', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
    array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
    array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
    array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
    array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55'),
);

// Save each row of the data
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}

// Close the file
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me: `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $content)`